# How can I call the operator-array-function via Mirrors in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

This works in Dart-VM:

```dart
final List<String> names = [ "Bob", "JOE" ];
final InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflect(names);

final Symbol function = new Symbol("[]");

final InstanceMirror getField = instanceMirror.invoke(function,[ 1 ]);
context = getField.reflectee;
_logger.info("Value $context"); // Shows JOE
```

but it fails if I compile it to JS.
**Error message**: `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]' Receiver: Instance of 'JSArray' Arguments: [1]'

I also tried it with elementAt instead of [] but then **I get**: `Unsupported operation: Can't use 'elementAt:1' in reflection because it is not included in a @MirrorsUsed annotation.`

Comment: And did you add it to `@MirrorsUsed`? Does it work when you create JS using `pub build --mode=debug`?

Comment: Arrrggg.... Thanks - you pointed me (again) in the right direction. Please see my answer.

Comment: I hope the "Arrrggg" is not because I pointed you in a direction :p

Comment: For sure not!!!! Thanks again! The "Arrrggg" goes to myself for being blind for the solution.

Comment: Drive by comment: if you can, use `const Symbol(...)` instead of `new Symbol(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

This class produced the error from above (first sample was a bit reduced...)

```dart
const MdlComponentModelAnnotation MdlComponentModel = const MdlComponentModelAnnotation();

@MdlComponentModel
class ModelTest {

    final ObservableProperty<String> wifi = new ObservableProperty<String>("never");

    @MdlComponentModel // useless - but lights made this problem...
    final List<ObservableProperty<String>> lights = [ new ObservableProperty<String>(""), new ObservableProperty<String>("") ];

    final ObservableProperty<int> intensity = new ObservableProperty<int>(90);
}
```

This is how my `@MirrorsUsed' looks like after @Günther pointed me to the right direction:

```
@MirrorsUsed(metaTargets: const [ MdlComponentModelAnnotation ],
    targets: const [ 'List' ],
    symbols: const [ '[]' ])
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

**Both! "targets" (List) and "symbols" ([]) were necessary!**